# inserting variable names into functions

Tags: c++, function, variables

I don't know what this is called, but I need to insert a variable name into a function. How do I reduce the following code? I've get the skeleton of the function written, but don't know how to make it work.

```
    void function(int x, int y, char name)
    {
    ((x <= ([name]_x + [name]button_w)) && (x > [name]button_x) &&
    (y <= ([name]button_y + [name]button_h)) && (y > [name]button_y))
    }


    if ((mouse_x <= (createbutton_x + createbutton_w)) && (mouse_x > createbutton_x) &&
(mouse_y <= (createbutton_y + createbutton_h)) && (mouse_y > createbutton_y))
        useCreate_Clip = CREATE_HOVER;
    else
        useCreate_Clip = CREATE_DEFAULT;
            

    if ((mouse_x <= (creditsbutton_x + creditsbutton_w)) && (mouse_x > creditsbutton_x) &&
(mouse_y <= (creditsbutton_y + creditsbutton_h)) && (mouse_y > creditsbutton_y))
    useCredits_Clip = CREDITS_HOVER;
else
    useCredits_Clip = CREDITS_DEFAULT;

        
if ((mouse_x <= (exitbutton_x + exitbutton_w)) && (mouse_x > exitbutton_x) &&
(mouse_y <= (exitbutton_y + exitbutton_h)) && (mouse_y > exitbutton_y))
    useExit_Clip = EXIT_HOVER;
else
    useExit_Clip = EXIT_DEFAULT;
```

Comment: pass in an instance (or reference to an instance) of a type, for example a struct? then `[name]_x` would become something like `inst.x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that; variable names only exist in source code and are not data.

Define a suitable data type and pass instances of that type to the function.

```
struct Button
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
};

bool inside(int x, int y, const Button& button)
{
    return x <= button.x + button.w && x > button.x &&
           y <= button.y + button.h && y > button.y;
}

//...
Button createbutton;
Button creditsbutton;
Button exitbutton;
// ...
useCreate_Clip = inside(mouse_x, mouse_y, createButton) ? CREATE_HOVER : CREATE_DEFAULT;
useCredits_Clip = inside(mouse_x, mouse_y, creditsButton) ? CREDITS_HOVER : CREDITS_DEFAULT;
//...
```

Comment: Thank you! These are just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you could take, but here's one (not tested but should show the idea):

```
template <typename ResultT>
ResultT function(int mouse_x, int mouse_y, 
     int button_h, int button_w, int button_x, int button_y,
     ResultT result_true, ResultT result_false)
{
  return 
      ((mouse_x <= (button_x + button_w)) && 
      (mouse_x > button_x) &&
      (mouse_y <= (button_y + button_h)) && 
      (mouse_y > button_y))
    ? result_true : result_false;
}

useCreate_Clip = function(mouse_x, mouse_y, createbutton_h,
    createbutton_w, createbutton_x, createbutton_y, 
    CREATE_HOVER, CREATE_DEFAULT);
        
useCredits_Clip = function(mouse_x, mouse_y, creditsbutton_h,
    creditsbutton_w, creditsbutton_x, creditsbutton_y, 
    CREDITS_HOVER, CREDITS_DEFAULT);
         
useExit_Clip = function(mouse_x, mouse_y, exitbutton_h,
    exitbutton_w, exitbutton_x, exitbutton_y, 
    EXIT_HOVER, EXIT_DEFAULT);
```

If you would sub-partition your member variables, changing

```
struct Thing {
    int createbutton_h, createbutton_w;
    int createbutton_x, createbutton_y;
    int creditsbutton_h, creditsbutton_w;
    int creditsbutton_x, creditsbutton_y; 
    int exitbutton_h, exitbutton_w, exitbutton_x, exitbutton_y;
};
```

into something like:

```
struct Button {
   int h, w, x, y;
};

struct Thing {
    Button create_button;
    Button credits_button;
    Button exit_button;
};
```

Then you could pass the whole bunch to your function at once:

```
template <typename ResultT>
ResultT function(int mouse_x, int mouse_y, 
     Button const& button,
     ResultT result_true, ResultT result_false)
{
  return 
      ((mouse_x <= (button.x + button.w)) && 
      (mouse_x > button.x) &&
      (mouse_y <= (button.y + button.h)) && 
      (mouse_y > button.y))
    ? result_true : result_false;
}

useCreate_Clip = function(mouse_x, mouse_y, createbutton,
    CREATE_HOVER, CREATE_DEFAULT);
        
useCredits_Clip = function(mouse_x, mouse_y, creditsbutton,
    CREDITS_HOVER, CREDITS_DEFAULT);
         
useExit_Clip = function(mouse_x, mouse_y, exitbutton,
    EXIT_HOVER, EXIT_DEFAULT);
```

Also, I made ResultT a template since it's not shown what type your values are, or if the use_*_Clip are the same type or not.